# How to update database functions in SQL Server project

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, t-sql

I have a SQL Server project in Visual Studio. I keep there all my table definitions, and whenever I make a change, I select publish and the changes are automatically applied to the target database after comparing the schemas.

This all works fine with `TABLE`s and `VIEW`s, however this doesn't update `FUNCTION`s and `PROCEDURE`s when I change the inner queries/logic.

Is there a way to have `FUNCTION`s automatically update in this scenario?

My SQL file containing the functions looks like this

```
CREATE FUNCTION Function1()
    RETURNS TABLE
        AS
        RETURN
            (
                *query*
            )

GO

CREATE FUNCTION Function2()
    RETURNS TABLE
        AS
        RETURN
            (
                *query*
            )

GO
```

Comment: I've never seen this happen before. If you do a schema compare, are they different? If you generate the change script, do the objects appear in there?

Answer (score 0):

Inline table function can have data modified by INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE in the same condition of view :

- The modification can only target one table of the function
- No transformation must by applied on published columns of the UDF
- Some operators cannot be used like UNION, INETERSECT or EXCEPT

Example :

```
CREATE TABLE dee (A int);
CREATE TABLE dum (B int);
GO

CREATE FUNCTION F_DEE_DUM (@A_DEE INT, @B_DUM INT)
RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN (SELECT *
        FROM   dee FULL OUTER JOIN dum ON A = B
        WHERE  @A_DEE IS NULL OR A = @A_DEE
         AND   @B_DUM IS NULL OR B= @B_DUM)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.F_DEE_DUM(NULL, NULL) (A) VALUES (0), (1);

INSERT INTO dbo.F_DEE_DUM(NULL, NULL) (B) VALUES (1), (2), (3);

UPDATE dbo.F_DEE_DUM(NULL, NULL) SET A = A + 1;

UPDATE dbo.F_DEE_DUM(NULL, NULL) SET B = B - 1;
```